# Linq SQL generation for pagination

Tags: oracle, performance, linq, odp.net

Using EF6, ODP.NET 12.2 and Oracle 12.2 server, I have the following table:

```
id  raw(16)
number  number(19)
name    varchar2(100 char) not null
description varchar2(100 char) not null
```

Indexes on (Name) and (Name, Description)

The following LINQ query:

```
db.SAMPLES.OrderBy(p => p.NAME).ThenBy(p => p.DESCRIPTION).Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

Produces this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM ( 
 SELECT 
 "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
 "Extent1"."NUMBER" AS "NUMBER", 
 "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME"
 FROM ( SELECT "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", "Extent1"."NUMBER" AS "NUMBER", "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC) AS "row_number"
  FROM "ZENKI"."SAMPLEs" "Extent1"
 )  "Extent1"
 WHERE ("Extent1"."row_number" > 0)
 ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC
 )
 WHERE (ROWNUM <= (10) )
```

The query works fine but performance is not good. Apparently, Oracle is not using the index due to the (extra??) order by (ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC).

The execution plan for the query is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name      | Rows   | Bytes    | Cost | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |           |     10 |     2250 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   COUNT STOPKEY                    |           |        |          |      |          |
|   2 |    VIEW                            |           |     10 |     2250 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY          |           |     10 |     2380 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 4 |      VIEW                          |           |     10 |     2380 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   5 |       WINDOW NOSORT                |           |     10 |     1300 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   6 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | SAMPLEs   | 245376 | 31898880 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |         INDEX FULL SCAN            | INDEX_SP1 |     10 |          |    1 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
* 3 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
* 4 - filter("Extent1"."row_number">0)
```

If I remove the last order by, query is fast and produces same result. And the execution plan becomes:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name      | Rows   | Bytes    | Cost | Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |           |     10 |     2380 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   COUNT STOPKEY                  |           |        |          |      |          |
| * 2 |    VIEW                          |           |     10 |     2380 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     WINDOW NOSORT                |           |     10 |     1300 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | SAMPLEs   | 245376 | 31898880 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   5 |       INDEX FULL SCAN            | INDEX_SP1 |     10 |          |    1 | 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
* 2 - filter("Extent1"."row_number">0)
```

After a lot of googling I asked in the ODP.NET forum and got this:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4126265

Seems that odp.net has no control (or limited) over the generated SQL. I thought that the providers generates SQL from the expression tree, so how can this be true? Has anyone else this problem with this type of queries?

**Update:**

Thread in LINQ forum:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6174ef9-a832-45da-8345-b97441d40363/linq-query-pagination-sql-generation?forum=linqtosql

**Update 1:**

Using a data type of Number instead of varchar for the order by produces a different explain plan and is very fast, so I begin to think that this is related in any way eith the data type.

Comment: As IQueryable has no AsUnordered, you  can try adding .Distinct() after the take.

Comment: Same performance result

Comment: As you saw in the ODP.NET forums, this is one of the pain points of using an ORM... the potential for inefficient SQL. Issues like this will always keep cropping up and can be due to EF bugs or ODP.NET bugs.  The APPLY keyword was the worst offender in the history of EF.. for many years only SQL Server worked when the expression tree indicated an "APPLY" was needed. Not just Oracle, but no other databases could handle that situation. In the end MS required databases add the APPLY keyword or throw an error.

Comment: @ChristianShay I can unserstand your point, what really bothers me is that this query seems to be very common. Nobody has tried to use a pagination query using EF and Oracle?

Comment: It may be a bug in ODP.NET or it may not be. The problem is, the bug gets fixed and then the expression tree changes in a future EF release and exposes another different bug or inefficiency. I'm just pointing out a weakness in ORMs.

Comment: Maybe you are right, thing is, same LINQ query is blighty fast using SQL Server and you just have to create an index on the ordered column, how Oracle expect people to use their database when using an ORM solution if queries are such inneficient or dificult to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't help, I don't use software you do. Though, as noone replied within 12 hours & regarding that it is Saturday and I have some time to spare, I'd like to say a few words.

> The following LINQ query (...) Produces this SQL (...)

(a little bit formatted to improve readability; I've marked A, B and C parts of the query which will be discussed later):

```
-- C
SELECT * 
 FROM (-- B
       SELECT 
          "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
          "Extent1"."NUMBER" AS "NUMBER", 
          "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME"
       FROM (-- A
             SELECT "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
                    "Extent1"."NUMBER" AS "NUMBER", 
                    "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC) AS "row_number"
             FROM "ZENKI"."SAMPLEs" "Extent1"
            )  "Extent1"
       WHERE ("Extent1"."row_number" > 0)
       ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC
      )
 WHERE (ROWNUM <= (10) );
```

If we go from the inner, A query, here are some comments:

**A:** ROW_NUMBER "ranks" rows ordered by NAME ASC. That's OK.

```
SELECT "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
       "Extent1"."NUMBER" AS "NUMBER", 
       "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC) AS "row_number"
  FROM "ZENKI"."SAMPLEs" "Extent1"
```

**B:** WHERE clause is unnecessary; ROW_NUMBER is always > 0. ORDER BY is unnecessary as well, because of ROW_NUMBER used in A query, which makes the whole B query a surplus.

```
select id, number, name
from A
where row_number > 0
ORDER BY NAME asc
```

**C:** WHERE clause would make sense if there wasn't ROW_NUMBER produced by the A query; use one of those, not both

```
select *
from B
where rownum <= 10
```

Basically, this might do the job as well:

```
select *
from A
where row_number <= 10
```

i.e. if you could make LINQ produce something like this, performance might also benefit.

```
select *
from (SELECT "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
        "Extent1"."NUMBER" AS "NUMBER", 
        "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."NAME" ASC) AS "row_number"
      FROM "ZENKI"."SAMPLEs" "Extent1" 
    )
where row_number <= 10
```

Just being curious: if you run it, how does it perform? Does it return the desired result at all? If answers are "good & yes", maybe you could try to persuade LINQ to produce a different query.

Comment: It runs very fast. The original SQL generated query already is lightning-fast removing the extra order by. The additional where clausule you remove is needed for the rest of the page (it's a pagination query). Question is, how to make LINQ to generate a better query, or how to change the original LINQ skip-take query ir order to generate a better SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I don't know :( I was hoping that you can set *something* up and make LINQ produce a "smarter" query. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!